# Something strange about importing quad opamps in Altium

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I'm trying to import a quad opamp in altium and I'm doing everything right according to what other posters have told me but I seem to be having trouble.

I imported all four sections of the part from the multi part schematic, but when I try to update the PCB doc it imports 4 separate IC's instead of just one. Has anyone ever imported a part like this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's kind of logical that altium can't puit them into one physical package before it knows your schematic numbering. Assign actual numbers instead of "U?" to the schematic symbol (there's an "automatic part numbering" button somewhere, almost certainly), and try again.